# Does the iPad 2 have a TV Out?

Tags: ipad

Can someone help me get started on showing iPad 2 videos (and possibly photos) easily on my TV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/

> - Video mirroring and video out
>     support: Up to 1080p with Apple
>     Digital AV Adapter or Apple VGA
>     Adapter (cables sold separately)
> - Video out support at 576p and 480p
>     with Apple Component AV Cable; 576i
>     and 480i with Apple Composite AV
>     Cable

Comment: Does this mean that you can see your iPad screen of any application in your TV with Apple Composite AV Cable? - I am unsuccessful in mirroring applications in my TV with the given cable. - It seems that it is impossible without jailbreaking the device.

Comment: Whether the mirroring works or not depends on whether the app developer has it supported. It can be disabled or enabled at their choice.